# How to export posts and keep html tags in the title

Tags: export

If my post title is :    `Hello <b>world</b>`

When exporting the posts with built-in Tools/Export, html tags are removed.
I don't want that.

I have 9K posts to export with valuable styling in all titles, so even if it is not the best practice, these tags need to be kept.

In what file is the xml generated ?
Or is there some kind of hook for this ?

Thank you.

Comment: You're not supposed to be able to have HTML tags in a title, the only reason you've been able to put them in is because as an administrator/super admin you're given the `unfiltered_html` capability, which lets you do dangerous things. Even if your XML file contained the tags in the header on export, there's no guarantee that they won't be stripped out on import, or that the theme on the other site will even support it

Comment: @TomJNowell Sure.  But i have 9K posts to export with valuable styling in all titles.  I need to find a way.   Thanx for the tip!

Comment: How are you exporting the data? are you using a plugin or you wrote some custom code?

Comment: @jDelforge also note that any inline styling or tags can play havoc with RSS, AMP, Google, FB, twitter, OEmbed previews, etc etc OG tags can mitigate some of this but it's still an issue. You're not supposed to have inline styling in titles. Are all your tags and styles the same as what's in your question? Were you using this to try and create sub-titles?

Comment: @Buttered_Toast  Post edited :  I'm exporting with built-in Tools/Export.  It is simple and complete for my needs... I just have a problem with the titles.

Comment: @TomJNowell.  9,000 posts with valuable styling to be kept in all titles.  Different tags.  span with style, br, b, i, all kinds.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the file `wp-admin/includes/export.php`

Within the post loop, line 545, simply replace

```
$title = apply_filters( 'the_title_rss', $post->post_title );
```

with

```
$title = $post->post_title;
```

Comment: That alone is not enough, you will also need to wrap the title in a CDATA tag. On line 568 instead of <title><?php echo $title; ?></title> type <title><![CDATA[<?php echo $title; ?>]]></title>, this will "tell" parsers that this is not an xml tag

Comment: Ok thank you.  It is working without the CDATA (only export/import on another wp), but i take note of it.

Comment: This is extreme bad practice, you must ***never*** modify files in `wp-admin` or `wp-includes`

Comment: You are correct that this should not be a permanent "fix" and that you should never edit core wordpress files directly, but if its for a single time use and the code is reverted back to the original there is nothing wrong about it. On occasion you will encounter a problem that will require you to edit core file/s, like OPs problem, just make sure to remove all your changes after.

Comment: @TomJNowell It fixes my problem.  I export the posts, then i just discard my change on the repo.

Comment: The line that's being changed is a hook. You can just unhook everything on that action instead of removing the action completely. This is extreme bad practice, so much so that this solution is not possible on a lot of hosts due to security measures

Comment: E.g. `remove_all_filters( 'the_title_rss' )`

Comment: Not only that, the line mentioned in this answer does not exist in WordPress 5.7, a dedicated filter and cdata tag handling was added too https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/export.php#L552